# ActiveMQ Artemis ha=true and SSL connector

Tags: ssl, activemq-artemis

I've activated SSL support on ActiveMQ Artemis (version 2.16) with:

```xml
    <acceptor name="artemis">tcp://{{ ansible_host }}:61616?sslEnabled=true;keyStorePath={{ artemis_broker_dir }}/etc/artemis-keystore.p12;keyStorePassword={{ artemis_keystore_password }}</acceptor>
```

which seems to work as expected, but after activating the cluster stop forming as it had a reference to a connector that didn't trust the self signed certificate I've used. Therefore updated to:

```xml
    <connectors>
        <!-- Connector used to be announced through cluster connections and notifications -->
        <connector name="artemis">tcp://{{ ansible_host }}:61616?sslEnabled=true;trustStorePath={{ artemis_broker_dir }}/etc/artemis-truststore.p12;trustStorePassword={{ artemis_truststore_password }}</connector>
    </connectors>
```

Great, now to cluster is working again.
The problem is when I use the client with HA=true it does the discovery connection to the server correctly (as I pass the config to a local trust store), but then it retrieves the connection configuration from the server and is trying to use the trustStorePath from the server, that doesn't exist on the client. Already tried to use forceSSLParameters=true after checking the code, but doesn't seems to solve the problem. How can I tell the client that I want to use the client truststore instead of the server one?

Stack from the client side displaying the server side path instead of the client one (used on the initial discovery connection):

```
[DEBUG] 2021-07-12 15:16:48.402 [Thread-3 (ActiveMQ-client-netty-threads)] SSLContextFactory - Creating SSL context with configuration 
trustStorePassword=winkwink
port=61616
sslEnabled=true
host=messaging-03.domain.pt
trustStorePath=/opt/artemis/etc/artemis-truststore.p12
[WARN ] 2021-07-12 15:16:48.405 [Thread-3 (ActiveMQ-client-netty-threads)] ChannelInitializer - Failed to initialize a channel. Closing: [id: 0x0e72e4b8]
java.lang.Exception: Failed to find a store at /opt/artemis/etc/artemis-truststore.p12
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.ssl.SSLSupport.validateStoreURL(SSLSupport.java:314) ~[artemis-core-client-2.16.0.jar:2.16.0]
```

Comment: Can you provide the URL which the client is using? Are you setting any SSL system properties on the client?

Comment: yes I am. From the log: ?trustStorePassword=****&forceSSLParameters=true&port=61616&sslEnabled=true&host=messaging-01.domain.pt&trustAll=false&trustStorePath=file:/C:/repositories/jms-app/build/resources/main/artemis-trust-dev-p12

Comment: I do the first discovery connection with that config and it works...I get the response with topology, but then the topology is using the definition from the server and seems to ignore my client "discover" config.

Comment: sorry, not system properties...I'm setting all programmatically via a Map in the TransportConfiguration. So "forceSSLParameters=true" will not affect anything. I've already remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the standard Java SSL system properties, e.g.:

- `javax.net.ssl.keyStore`
- `javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword`
- `javax.net.ssl.trustStore`
- `javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword`

Or if those are already in use in your client you can use these which are specific to ActiveMQ Artemis:

- `org.apache.activemq.ssl.keyStore`
- `org.apache.activemq.ssl.keyStorePassword`
- `org.apache.activemq.ssl.trustStore`
- `org.apache.activemq.ssl.trustStorePassword`

This is all described in [the documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/configuring-transports.html#configuring-netty-ssl).

Another option would be to simply specify the *name* of the keystore and truststore on the `connector` in `broker.xml` (e.g. `artemis-keystore.p12` & `artemis-truststore.p12` respectively). As long as the file is on the classpath (e.g. in the broker's `etc` directory) then it will be found. Then the client just needs to use artifacts with the same name which are also on its classpath. You can see this in action in the ["ssl-enabled" example](https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis/blob/36a771150b3ce7a0d889f7df3b7c7a6cd37769f7/examples/features/standard/ssl-enabled/src/main/resources/activemq/server0/broker.xml#L34) shipped with the broker.

In my opinion, the best option is simply to get your SSL certificates signed by a trusted authority rather than self-signing. Then you won't need to mess with the truststore at all and the clients will just work.

Comment: Also thought in using the systems properties as an workaround during the night. Going to make sure it works to mark the answer as the solution. Thanks :) For using only the name I think it doesn't work as it loads an URL and it's not valid, but can have a look again. Regarding the last comment, also agree and was the proposal of a co-worker as well.

Comment: Using the name should definitely work. This is what the "ssl-enabled" example does. I added a link to my answer.

Comment: Yes, I think I edit the comment removing my statement, as I had a close look to the code and on the catch block there's the code for lookup on the classpath.